# Use showType in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a program using AngularJS (plnkr link included) which is showing data from JSON. I want to use `showType` to display one screen to another screen.

**Plnkr link:** http://plnkr.co/edit/6gSTwOd2tSiw1rXuOCXg?p=preview

**JSON structure:**

```
{
  "1": {
    "venture": "XYZ Informatics",
    "member": [
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "email": "abcd@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "message": "This is good day",
    "isclicked": true
  },
  "2": {
    "venture": "BBC Informatics",
    "member": [
      {
        "name": "xyz",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "message": "This is bad day",
    "isclicked": false
  }
}
```

**It is showing output:**

```
XYZ Informatics
BBC Informatics
```

It is also giving the background color of table row red and green by checking `"isclicked": false` and  `"isclicked": true`

There is another one `div data-show` . I want to make the table row clickable. If I click the `XYZ Informatics` then it will call the `div data-show` and will display the data of XYZ Informatics, next window will look like,

```
abcd
This is good day
```

There is a button 'Back'. After clicking on button, we will come back to the previous screen (the listing data) and the color of the background color selected row will be vanished when it comes back.

Comment: What do you mean use showType? This looks like you want all of your logic done for you. If there is particular points at which you are getting stuck please point those out. Your plunker just shows two table rows and empty lists (since you are accessing the data wrong, and data is not available at that point). Your question doesnt clearly state which part works and which doesn't. Please clarify.

Comment: Please check again. I am getting data from api.json. List is showing in the table.

Comment: Yes, you are getting the data, but your list is empty is it not? its because  {{ data.member.name }} is invalid, data does not exist at this point in the scope, it might work if it was {{datas.1.member[0].name }}. Anyway other than getting the json and displaying a table what have you tried in order to achieve what you need?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking. I want to use that data after clicking on item from first screen. This data should show in second screen.

Comment: Well, try adding a router, making a second view, then passing the desired data to the second view and displaying as required. Update the ajax on the backend as required. Thats how you can go about solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a start to show you how you can accomplish showing different data based on clicking a row.

```
 <table ng-hide="nextData.isclicked" style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="data in datas">

          <td ng-style="getColor(data)">
            <a href="#" ng-click="data.isclicked = true; $parent.nextData = data">{{ data.venture }}
            </a>
          </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div ng-if="nextData.isclicked" class="data-show">
    <ul>
      <li> {{ nextData.member[0].name }} </li>
      <li> {{ nextData.message }}</li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="nextData.isclicked = false; nextData = {};">Back</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

link to updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/z86eie7Zfa5zDAK4FhA2?p=preview

Comment: It is almost near. But, I don't want to show the table in the same screen when we click on item. Also, once we click on item, it's background-color should be white

Comment: I added a ng-hide to hide the table if an item is clicked.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. your updated link solved the screen problem. But, I want to remove back-ground color of selected row too when we click on back.

Comment: I fixed that too, by changing the function getColor to return white if isclicked is marked true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, I forked your Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bI7uYGbMwtmg114BnbrT?p=preview).

I've added a button for data details, but of course you can use element you want.

- Important thing is to store clicked data in disp.details
  (`ng-click="disp.details = data"`).
- Then, you can show data infos using disp.details.

When you click `Details` it shows data infos, and `Back button` hide elements.

**HTML body:**

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="displayController as disp">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="data in datas" >
            <td ng-style="getColor(data)">{{ data.venture }}</td>
            <td><button ng-click="disp.details = data">Details</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div ng-show="disp.details != null">
        <ul>
          <li> Name: {{disp.details.member[0].name}}</li>
          <li> Email: {{disp.details.member[0].email}}</li>
          <li> Message: {{disp.details.message}}</li>
        </ul>
        <button ng-click="disp.details = null">Back</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```